# How to decide what is the relevant group in a precsion and recall computation?

Tags: java, precision, information-retrieval, precision-recall

One of the most famous measurements for an `information retrieval` system is to compute its `precision` and `recall`. For both cases, we need to compute the number of total relevant documents and compare it with the documents that the system has returned. My question is that how can we find this `super set` of relevant documents in following scenario:

Consider we have an academic search engine which its job is to accept a full name of an academic paper and base on some algorithms, it returns a list of relevant papers. Here, to judge whether or not the system has a good accuracy, we wish to calculate its precision and recall. But We do not know how can we produce a set of relevant papers -which the search engine should return them, regarding to different user's query- and accordingly, computing the precision and recall.

Answer (score 0):

Most relevant document sets for system design involve showing documents to a user (real person).

**Non-human evaluation:**

You could probably come up with a "fake" evaluation in your particular instance. I would expect that the highest ranked paper for the paper "Variations in relevance judgments and the measurement of retrieval effectiveness" [1] would be that paper itself. So you could take your data and create an automatic evaluation. It wouldn't tell you if your system was really finding new things (which you care about), but it would tell you if your system was terrible or not.

e.g. If you were at a McDonald's, and you asked a mapping system where the nearest McDonald's was, and it didn't find the one you were at, you would know this to be some kind of system failure.

**For a real evaluation:**

You come up with a set queries, and you judge the top *K* results from your systems for each of them. In practice, you can't look at all millions of papers for each query -- so you approximate the recall set by the recall set you currently know about. This is why it's important to have some diversity in the systems you're pooling. Relevance is tricky; people disagree a lot on what documents are relevant to a query.

In your case: people will disagree about what papers are relevant to another paper. But that's largely okay, since they will mostly agree on the obvious ones.

**Disagreement is okay if you're comparing systems:**

This paradigm only makes sense if you're comparing different information retrieval systems. It doesn't help you understand how good a single system is, but it helps you determine if one system is better than the other reliably [1].

[1] Voorhees, Ellen M. "Variations in relevance judgments and the measurement of retrieval effectiveness." Information processing & management 36.5 (2000): 697-716.

Comment: `so you approximate the recall set by the recall set you currently know about` well, the problem is how to get this current state?

Comment: You show the top 10 results from your system to a user, and ask them if they are relevant or not. Suppose they mark 7 of those 10 as relevant. Then your recall set is those seven documents.

Comment: By any chance, did you read the whole paper that you have cited in your answer? I have realized there are some way to calculate precision and recall without asking users for their feedback. By far, what I got from that paper is that we can make a relative precision and recall (page 5). Moreover, we can combine other systems' results together and then use it as a reference for computing the precision and recall, without asking users. (Cont...)

Comment: (...Cont.) I do know the author of paper used gain those rankings by asking assessors to rank documents, but is that possible we implement different systems programmatically and hence, using their output as a measurement for building different relevance sets and etc ?

Comment: You'd be asserting that taking the majority vote of your systems would be a good estimate for perfect. I suspect there is some research doing this, but I don't know of it offhand.

Unfortunately, for most IR tasks, our state of the art systems are still pretty far away from perfect. In, e.g. (the recent EsdRank paper http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./callan/Papers/cikm15-cx.pdf) they have a state-of-the-art approach to ranking, and on the web collections, but their best approach is less than 1/4 of the optimal ranking in the top 20 (NDCG@20 = .221).

Comment: but what I said in my last two comments is what I understood from the `Voorhees, Ellen M. "Variations in relevance judgments and the measurement of retrieval effectiveness." Information processing & management 36.5 (2000): 697-716.`. Did you read that paper carefully? even it is an old paper, but I found it interesting and somehow opened some dead end of my evaluation.

Comment: On the fifth page (p. 701), the results in Table 2 are the results of evaluating one human against another. This is possible because we believe each human to be a valid estimator of truth. We don't know that about systems. If you had a system that you believed to be perfect, you could certainly measure against that system's performance. But if you developed a new system that brought in better, unseen results, or just corrected the original system's false positives, it would look bad in comparison, and you wouldn't know.